# Eclipse Main menu MouseHover

Tags: eclipse, menu, listener, mousehover

i would like to know if it possible in eclipse,using plug-in, to get notified by a listener (or other methods) , when the cursor mouse hovers over Main menu item (e.g File) , before i click and show the menu ???

Thanks

Amir

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a reference to the MenuItem then you can add an ArmListener to MenuItem.addArmListener(ArmListener). This will notify the listener when the user is hovering over it.

Comment: Quick Answer!! :)
According to what you say,correct me if i am wrong ,but it Works only after i clicked on the Main Menu (e.g File), and that i don't need. my purpose is to get notified when i hover over the menu before i click on it.

Comment: Yes, this is what ArmListener does, notifies on hover.